# Is there a term used to refer to a certain passage from Shemot?

Tags: minhag, words

I’m wondering if this passage from Shemot 34:6 is referred to with a “title” or “name”, if you will. There are many variations of the English translation. I like the one below.
I very much love this passage. It appears numerous times in Tehillim and elsewhere.
Is there a term that is used to identify it? Just curious…
Many thanks.
יְהוָה יְהוָה, אֵל רַחוּם וְחַנּוּן--אֶרֶךְ אַפַּיִם, וְרַב-חֶסֶד
The Lord is gracious and full of compassion, slow to anger and abounding in kindness…

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Attributes_of_Mercy

Comment: @JoelK that's not only *an* answer, it's *the* answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, Joel K and  יהושע ק